# Using applescript / automator to run illustrator batch process

Tags: applescript, batch-processing, automator, adobe-illustrator

Is there a way to get Automator or Applescript to run 'batch' processes in Adobe Illustrator?

I have a workflow that handles a number of steps - but the key one is to use Illustrator variable data sets to replace two embedded eps files (one of a symbol and one of some text) and a bit of text with a product code.

I'm basically running through this:
http://hypertransitory.com/blog/2014/05/27/use-adobe-illustrator-variable-data-xml/

Except I have some php spitting out the xml that illustrator requires to use for data.

So I have my xml, and if I run a batch process from within illustrator that works fine - trouble is I want to do this multiple times - and each time I want the files to save in the same location. I can get automator to run an action in illustrator, but I can't create an action to load in and run through the data sets from the xml, saving each one. The only way illustrator seems to let you use the variable data sets is via 'batch' - which means you have to provide it with the 'Destination' to export the files to every time (and you can't use it as a step in Automator).

I'm using Illustrator CC (so I believe that's referred to as illustrator 17 in applescript) and OSX 10.10 (if that's relevant)

I'm new to applescript and am busy learning the syntax - but I can't find anything that seems to indicate this is going to be possible!

Answer (score 0):

You can use Illustrator-friendly scripting languages to "manually" change out the datasets within the Illustrator document and output the files into your manually-coded location. If you can find the Applescript commands to do this, you can use it, otherwise you can make a .jsx extendscript and trigger it with your Applescript.

Answer (score 0):

There are also a couple of sets of `Illustrator Automator` actions, which may be of use to you. `Ai Actions` and `AI Automator Action Pack`, both of which are available on the Mac app store. Not as versatile as coding your own bespoke solution using AppleScript (which is how I'd probably approach the problem), but much easier to implement. For the sake of transparency, I'm the developer of the former.

Comment: Thanks - actually had bought and managed to get what I needed running (to an extent) using the latter, but it's now looking too complex for automator to handle (it keeps hanging)... so potentially looking for that bespoke solution using AppleScript as you suggest...